# NUnit / Testdriven.Net conflicting results

Tags: c#, nunit, testdriven.net

When I run this test in NUnit = Red Bar.

```
    [Test]
    public void ChangingValueViaPropertyDescriptorRaisesPropertyChangedNotification()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs pCEventArgs = null;
        subjectVM.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { pCEventArgs = e; };

        PropertyDescriptor descriptor = subjectVM.GetProperties().Find(schoolMeta.Name, false);

        descriptor.SetValue(null, "School's out for summer.");

        Assert.IsNotNull(pCEventArgs);
        Assert.AreEqual("School", pCEventArgs.PropertyName);
    }
```

However, when I run this test from within Visual Studio with Testdriven.Net it passes (it's also ok when run from a console app).

When it fails with NUnit it's because PropertyChanged is null, subjectVM is a View Model class that inherits PropertyChanged from a base class.

Am I to blame, or am I looking at a NUnit bug?

Comment: Did you mean PropertyChanged is null or pcEventArgs is null with NUnit?

Comment: Different test harnesses execute tests in different orders - does this test have an implicit dependency on the order in which it's executed? Perhaps another test is doing something fishy to `subjectVM`? (This looks plausible since it appears to be a class member.)

Comment: @Paolo, No I meant PropertyChanged is null, I discovered this by inserting exceptions at various places and running the test again from NUnit, so I know the NUnit test runner gets as far as if(PropertyChanged != null) but no further.

Comment: @Jeff, subjectVM is instantiated in SetUp simply subjectVM = new SubjectViewModel(subject) so the instance is unique to this test.

Comment: @Jeff, actually yes, the PropertyDescriptor list returned by GetProperties is static, I've removed thes static keyword from the declaration and the test runs, I think you win!

Comment: Hooray! That's a great, but mildly unnerving example of how effective unit tests can be. Test harnesses should run tests in a random order! There are a few randomizers out there, but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different test harnesses execute tests in different orders: if this test has an implicit dependency on the fixture's execution order, it could be causing this problem (I've been burned by this before).

My best guess is that another test is doing something fishy to `subjectVM` (or one of **its** members).